# What if ResultSet that is to be retrieved from database does not exist. how can i make the command issue a JOptionPane message in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans, jdbc

I would like to Know What if once the search button in clicked and the ID does not exist, where do i imput the Command to display a error..

```
else if(e.getSource() == btnSearch) {
  ResultSet rs = null;           
  rs = sD.getSummonID(txtSummonID.getText());
  Summon s = null;
  try {
    while(rs.next()) {
      s = new Summon(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("plateNum"), 
          rs.getDouble("amount"), rs.getString("recDate"), 
          rs.getString("location"), rs.getString("officer")); 
    }

    txtcarLicenceNo.setText(s.getCarLicenceNo());
    txtAmount.setText(Double.toString(s.getAmount()));
    txtLocation.setText(s.getLocation());
    txtOfficer.setText(s.getOfficerInCharge());                       
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.err.println("SQL Exception: " + ex);
  }
}
```

the other class looks like this

```
public ResultSet getSummonID(String summonID) {
  getConnection();
  try {
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM record WHERE id = " + summonID);                 

    return rs;
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println("SQL Exception: " + e);
    return rs;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rs = sD.getSummonID(txtSummonID.getText());
if(condition to check that your id is null) {
   //display pop up
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Id does not exists");
}else {
  // proceed further
  Summon s = null;
    try {
        while(rs.next())
        {s = new Summon(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("plateNum"), 
                rs.getDouble("amount"), rs.getString("recDate"), 
                rs.getString("location"), rs.getString("officer")); 
        }

          txtcarLicenceNo.setText(s.getCarLicenceNo());
          txtAmount.setText(Double.toString(s.getAmount()));
          txtLocation.setText(s.getLocation());
          txtOfficer.setText(s.getOfficerInCharge());                       
        }            
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        System.err.println("SQL Exception: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: resultset is never null

Comment: Please add suitable condition in if block.Which will be true for dispalying the pop up

Comment: Hey Hii Deepak.. The command u have suggested will only work if i click search with a black text.. what if i input a id number of 99 but my database only has 50 id's. how can i get the system to display pop up saying that the id does not exist.

Comment: @Vick  you can fire a query with the id entered `select from table where id= enteredid`.If this comes null then u can display a pop up saying that this id does not exists .If however any one tries to enter blank id u can dispaly pop up that .Please enter id

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, you will get a `NullPointerException` when there is no result fetch because your Summon object s is initialised to null:

```
    Summon s = null;
```

and when there is no result

```
 while(rs.next())
```

will never iterate to set your `s` object. To avoid Null Pointer exception you can introduces a null check as mentioned here:

```
while(rs.next())
            {s = new Summon(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("plateNum"), 
                    rs.getDouble("amount"), rs.getString("recDate"), 
                    rs.getString("location"), rs.getString("officer")); 
            }

              if(s != null) {
              txtcarLicenceNo.setText(s.getCarLicenceNo());
              txtAmount.setText(Double.toString(s.getAmount()));
              txtLocation.setText(s.getLocation());
              txtOfficer.setText(s.getOfficerInCharge());                       

              } else {
                   // display JOptionPane
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your error/info message");
              }
            }
```

Comment: Hey Bro Thanks alot.. I am still a newbie.. learning bit by bit everyday.

Comment: @Vick no worries, I'm glad that my answer was comprehensible to a newbie :-)